# IndexedDBShim polyfill version mismatch

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am using the polyfill indexedDBShim [Here](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim) and I have an error with it and I have no idea how I can debug it or know how I can fix it.

My error :

`unable to open database, version mismatch, '1' does not match the currentVersion of '1.0'`

It is working fine on the browser that indexedDB is compatible, but when I try it on Safari for example, I have this error..

I just did this :

```
var request = indexedDB.open( 'products', 1 );
request.onupgradeneeded = function( e ) {
    console.log('Upgrading...');
    var thisDB = e.target.result;

    if ( !thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains( "devices" ) ) {
        thisDB.createObjectStore( "devices", { keyPath: "title" } );
        thisDB.createIndex( "title", "title", { unique: true } );
    }
};

request.onsuccess = function( e ) {
    console.log('Success!');
    that.db = e.target.result;
    //that.saveProducts( data );
};

request.onerror = function( e ) {
    console.log('Error!');
    console.dir( e );
};
```

Can someone help me with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shim ends up in some bad business, let me tell you! (We get a lot of questions on it.)

First off, versions should neither be strings nor floats. They should be integers greater than zero per spec. So that ain't right regardless.

From my [dash](https://github.com/buley/dash/blob/master/documentation/databases.md) [docs](http://dashdb.com/#/docs/databases) on this:

> [`Version`](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-version) numbers are
>   positive whole numbers greater than zero. A programmer can set a
>   database's version manually or implictly by opening an existing
>   database name with a greater version number than the database
>   contains. While a database's name can never change, the database
>   version changes all the time.
>
> Specifying a version greater than the current allows us to entry a
>   "version change" transaction that enables database schema changes.
>   When no version is specified, the database will open with the most
>   recent database version.
>
> Database version numbers are stored as [8-byte "int long
>   long"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB#Opening_a_database)
>   in the underlying C programming language implementation of IDB  and
>   can number anywhere between `1` and `18446744073709551615`.

Here's how I'd debug/solve using regular IDB: open up the database without a version. That should open a connection using the most current version and the response object will give you the current version. Compare the two to find your application error.

Notably, database open requests should provide a couple attributes that help you keep a clean and consistant application state when `versionchange`ing: `event.newVersion` and `event.oldVersion`